# Primefaces Passing value by PF() function to dailog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to know if it is possible to pass value by PF() function to dialog in primefaces.

Comment: Do you want to set the value of an input field in a primefaces dialogbox?

Comment: i want to pass the value from PF function to dialog and then set the if condition because i have a look there and i want to show only relevant ID´s data. Not all ID data. Please have a look on this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832108/how-to-pass-param-values-from-pcommandlink-to-pdialog-in-the-same-page

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand.  What means `set the if condition`? What is `from PF function`? If you like to show/hide `relevant ID's data` via `rendered=` or `<c:if` there is no chance. These "conditionally show makers" only work server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PF function accepts one argument `widgetVar`, that is a string with a widget's variable name. It returns a widget object instance. That's it.

The question is nonsensical - it's probably a result of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). The linked closed question is not much better.